# МИтенки или митЕнки?

Tags: фонетика

Как правильно поставить ударение: мИтенки или митЕнки?

Comment: Народ, не ставьте метки от балды, пожалуйста. Если речь об ударениях, то это "фонетика"

Comment: Я поставила метку "орфоэпия", т.к. хотела написать и про [тэ] / [т'э] в слове "митенки" (слышала и такие варианты произношения), но потом отвлеклась и забыла. В том вариате, который есть, вы правы, нужна метка "фонетика".

Comment: >Если речь об ударениях, то это "фонетика"  
  
Спасибо, будем знать.

Answer (score 3):

МитЕнки. Как верно замечает Кузнецов "[франц. mitaine - рукавица]".

Я против вариативности. БТС Кузнецова - вообще полное собрание орфоэпических (и не только) ляпсусов, а тут двойной ляпсус. Он ссылается на французское происхождение и даёт "русское" ударение. Почему при этом он ставит ударение на И - большой вопрос. Хотя он вообще большой оригинал.

Других источников, предлагающих ударение на первый слог, не зафиксировано.

> Ресурс Грамота.ру дает справку :
> (grumant)

Вы бы хоть комментировали содержательно, когда даете два взаимоисключающих варианта.

Comment: Я показал путь, который может пройти любой вопрошающий : заглянуть в разные источники и составить свое личное мнение. Авторы словарей идут точно таким же путем. Ищут сведения, думают, потом пишут свой вариант. Опишите Ваш процесс поиска правильной формы слова.

Comment: Я так понимаю, жаба Вас придавила малеха? Бывает, бывает... Не поддавайтесь ей, иначе совсем можете задохнуться))) Более в словопрения с Вами вступать не буду, дабы форум не накалять))) Привет вашей жабе!

Comment: *МитЕнки... [франц. mitaine - рукавица]* Только по-французски Т твёрдая, а когда Е пишется, остаётся неоднозначность, твёрдо или мягко Т читать.