# Митенки-митЁнки-митэнки

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно произносить? мИтенки, митЁнки, митЭнки, мИтэнки. Все эти варианты слышала вживую.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [МИтенки или митЕнки?](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/17452/%d0%9c%d0%98%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%95%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1):

Правильно произносить с *тэ* и ударением на втором слоге, так, как этот слог произносят фpанцузы. Это подтверждает словарь иностранных слов, а также Ушаков.

Comment: Ушаков сильно устарел вообще, а источником орфоэпической истины никогда и не был.

Comment: Мой орфоэпический (Аванесов и др.) говорит то же самое.

Comment: Аванесов - это другое дело.